# c# Как обнаружить вторжение в память своей программы

Tags: c#, процесс, защита, виртуальная-память

Существуют различные программы по захвату текста с форм (например в ЯП Autoit, есть функция ControlGetText, которая считываем с контролера текст), есть программы, которые вообще позволяют влезать в память процесса, такие как Cheat Engine (например).

Собственно вопрос. Есть ли способ обнаружения "вторжения" в память своей программы? Как это можно реализовать? В какую сторону копать?

Comment: От квалифицированного взломщика вы не спасётесь, на своей машине юзер царь и бог, он может запустить вас хоть под аппаратным отладчиком.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Нашел интересный [ответ](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/137402/detect-if-another-process-reads-my-programms-memory):

Ничего не мешает злоумышленнику заморозить ваш процесс, сделать все необходимые действия и убить процесс => процесс не узнает ничего о том, что кто-то его читал. Можно так сделать дамп памяти и опять же процесс не будет знать, что кто-то читал его память.

Существуют [дебаггеры](https://x64dbg.com/#start), которые позволяют перелопатить ваш процесс по косточкам.

Как вы указали в своем вопросе, то самые банальный пример- это взлом компьютерных игр. Если бы разработчики имели универсальное решение, то все бы читеры давно вымерли, а они все плодятся и плодятся => нельзя защитить память своего приложение. Разработчики вынуждены использовать анти-читы и ловить подозрительные активности игроков.

Закрытость платформы, где юзер имеет ограниченные возможности, может обеспечить защиту от взлома процесса. Например, игровые консоли.

Еще один выход- это хранить важную информацию на сервере, куда злоумышленник имеет меньшую вероятность попасть и время от времени выполнять верификацию клиента. Так, обычно, делается в ММОРПГ.

Подводя итог: Вы больше всего зависите от среды в которой работает ваше приложение. Если она имеет API для обнаружения, то используйте его, в противном случае у вас нету никаких возможностей, так как памятью рулит ОС, а не вы.

Например, у Windows есть [DEP](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/875352/a-detailed-description-of-the-data-execution-prevention-dep-feature-in), который мониторит память и предотвращает запуск вредоносного кода из стороннего процесса.

Comment: Эм.. DEP же никак не связан с внедрением кода в процесс? Ну если кто-то не накосячил и не сделал этот код в блоке данных.